# Google Sheets: need to sort and condense an inventory dataset by two factors including a SKU w/wildcard

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Using google sheets, I'm trying to build an inventory dashboard that will take a simply pasted in dataset and return clean inventory numbers arranged by location. Product units can be located in different locations, and have identifier SKUs that can have a variable letter code in them, plus an expanding number of possibilities for that SKU series letter.

So for example, I am hoping to break this:

| SKU | NAME | Quantity | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VD002C | Bob | 3 | Paris |
| VD002A | Bob | 5 | London |
| VD002A | Bob | 4 | Paris |
| VD007C | Fred | 6 | New York |
| VD007C | Fred | 5 | Paris |
| VD007C | Fred | 7 | Shanghai |
| VD007B | Fred | 4 | London |
| VD007B | Fred | 1 | Paris |

Into this:

| Name | SKU | Paris | London | New York | Shanghai |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bob | VD002* | 7 | 5 | 0 | 0 |
| Fred | VD007* | 6 | 4 | 6 | 7 |

where SKU "VD002*" could look like VD002A, VD002B, VD002C, VD002D, etc, but is ultimately all "Bob" and the A/B/C/D distinction doesn't matter, and any or all of those could be located in Paris, NYC, etc

I've been able to get any one or two of the factors to return right, but not all of them at the same time, and not reliably with the random number of possibilities we could see in the dataset. I'd guess I'm missing a step or five, and it's getting beyond my experience level.
Thank you!

Comment: These are both solid, although I think the query approach lends itself better to the regularity in output I'm looking for.
Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

*Here's one possible approach which you may adapt it accordingly:*

```js
=let(Σ,unique(filter({left(A2:A,5),B2:B},A2:A<>"")),
     Λ,torow(unique(tocol(D2:D,1))),
     vstack({"Name","SKU",Λ},map(index(Σ,,1),index(Σ,,2),lambda(x,y,hstack(y,x&"*",bycol(Λ,lambda(z,index(sumifs(C:C,D:D,z,left(A:A,5),x,B:B,y)))))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may also try `QUERY()` approach-

```
=QUERY(HSTACK(INDEX(LEFT(A2:A9,LEN(A2:A9)-1)),B2:D9),
"select Col2, Col1, sum(Col3) 
group by Col2, Col1 
pivot Col4 
label Col2 'Name', Col1 'SKU' ")
```

[image]